# Android: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" while building project after updating Room DB from v2.2.0 to (v2.2.1 .. v2.2.3)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room, androidx, android-studio-3.0

After I updated Room dependency from v2.2.0 to (v2.2.1 .. v2.2.3) then rebuild the project I got the following error, but if I downgrade it again to v2.2.0 it's work:

```
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDev2DebugKotlin
e: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Collections.singleton(Collections.java:4667)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverridingUtil.createAndBindFakeOverrides(OverridingUtil.java:521)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.OverridingUtil.generateOverridesInFunctionGroup(OverridingUtil.java:456)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.generateFakeOverrides(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:157)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getNonDeclaredFunctions(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:221)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.access$doGetFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope$functionDescriptors$1.invoke(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:446)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:521)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.AbstractLazyMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(AbstractLazyMemberScope.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:200)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.computeExtraDescriptors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$extraDescriptors$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$extraDescriptors$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorUtils.getAllDescriptors(DescriptorUtils.java:587)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.resolveMemberHeaders(LazyClassDescriptor.java:595)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.doForceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:565)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.lambda$new$4(LazyClassDescriptor.java:216)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor$$Lambda$125/339261534.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:561)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:135)


> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDev2DebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDev2DebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDev2DebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:361)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:354)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:340)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Internal compiler error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:148)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:143)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:429)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:339)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:296)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:268)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:539)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:524)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:507)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
    ... 30 more
```

More info from my environment that may help:

```
    // the used dependencies
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

- I use Android Studio 3.5.3
- Almost I use the latest version for all dependencies
- kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
- dagger_version = "2.25.4"
- snippets from app: build.gradle ->

  ```
  javaCompileOptions {
      annotationProcessorOptions {
          arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                       "room.incremental"   : "true",
                       "room.expandProjection":"true"]
      }
  }

  kapt {
   javacOptions {
      // Increase the max count of errors from annotation processors.
      // Default is 100.
      option("-Xmaxerrs", 5000)
   }
   useBuildCache = false
  }

  compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }

  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
    preDexLibraries = false
  }
  ```
- gradle.properties file ->

  ```
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512M -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx4g" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    kapt.incremental.apt=true
    android.databinding.incremental=true
    kotlin.code.style=official
    android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true
  ```

Comment: For some reason, the garbage collector is taking an excessive amount of time and recovers very little memory in each run

Answer (score -2):

change your gradle.properties to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m`